# How to change Electronjs title bar text without changing the Window dropdown document name?

Tags: electron

In Electonjs how can you change the window title bar without changing the name of the document in the Window dropdown Menu?

I'm trying to add a " - Edited" text to the window title bar once I edit a document that is loaded into the BrowserWindow. This worked. Once the document is edited I send an event to main.js and used win.setTitle() in main.js to toggle the " - Edited" text change on the window title bar (and also used the win.setDocumentEdited() in addition to change the state of that window property in main.js). But I'm using the default { role: "windowMenu" } in my menu template and so in the list of open windows in the Window dropdown menu it automatically adds the " - Edited" to that as well.

I was hoping to keep the document names in the Window dropdown menu the same (no " - Edited") while just adding that text to the title bar. Is this possible in Electron while using the { role: "windowMenu" } or would I have to custom roll my Window menu to make the title bar text and the Window menu text different?

[image: This works how I want, " - Edited" shown]

[image: I don't want the " - Edited" here]